# How to use StackOverflow ask button formatting in javafx app?

Tags: java, javafx-2, stack-overflow

I like the question formatting of stack overflow.
I am building a discussion forum kinda app in javafx.
Please guide me how can I do the same there?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is a little too broad a question for stack overflow. However you may find this [post on what technologoies stack exchange use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) formatting.

There are a few 3rd party components which allow authoring and rendering of Markdown in JavaFX.  You could adapt these for your forum application.  Listed in no particular order:

- [Brain Low: JavaFX Markdown Viewer](http://brainlow.blogspot.com/2012/10/javafx-markdown-viewer.html)
- [Markdown Pad FX](https://github.com/eugener/markdown-pad-fx)
- [Flowdown](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/flowdown)
- [MarkdownFX](https://bitbucket.org/atill/markdownfx)

I have not used any of the above projects.

Also there are many HTML based Markdown editors, so you another option is to embed a Markdown HTML Editor in a JavaFX WebView, though I think a native JavaFX solution would probably be preferred if you can get that to work well for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good start point for me.